# LNK2005 LNK1169 when having more than one C++ file inside my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

Trying to build and compress one of my files for an assignment in Visual Studio 2022 which has 5 C++ files in it. When I try to run one of them when there is all of them in there, I am provided with the error
`Unable to start program C:\Users\user\source\repos\CS102AS2_ZL\x64\Debug\CS102AS2_ZL.exe The system cannot find the file specified.`
It also then proceeds to say in the console

```
[LNK2005] main already defined in t1.obj | File T2.obj | Line 1
[LNK1169] one or more multiply defined symbols found | File CS102AS2_ZL.exe | Line 1
```

Line one in all of my code is `#include <iostream>`

If I try to run one of them by themselves then it's fine and the code works but as soon as I try run one when there's other files in the project then it breaks.
Below is the code for `t1.cpp` and `t2.cpp`

**T1.CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Declaring Variables
    float a, b, c, x1, x2, discriminant, realPart, imaginaryPart;
    // User Input
    cout << "Enter coefficients a, b and c: ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    // Calculation for square root
    if (discriminant > 0) {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

        // Outputs for square root
        cout << "Roots are real and unequal." << endl;
        cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
        cout << "x2 = " << x2 << endl;
    }

    else if (discriminant == 0) {
        cout << "Roots are real and equal." << endl;
        x1 = -b / (2 * a);
        x2 = -b / (2 * a);
        cout << "x1 = " << x1 << " x2 = " << x2 << endl;
    }

    else {
        realPart = -b / (2 * a);
        imaginaryPart = sqrt(-discriminant) / (2 * a);
        cout << "Roots are imaginary." << endl;
        cout << "x1 = " << realPart << "+" << imaginaryPart << "i" << endl;
        cout << "x2 = " << realPart << "-" << imaginaryPart << "i" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**T2.CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declaring Variables
    int i, start, end;
    int chk = 0, j;
    bool is_prime = true;

    // User Input
    cout << "\nEnter starting number: ";
    cin >> start;
    cout << "\n" "Enter final number: ";
    cin >> end;
    cout << "Number divisible by 7 from " << start << " to " << end << endl;
    cout << "******************************\n";

    // Dividing by 7
    for (i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    {
        if (i % 7 == 0)
        {
            // Divisible Output
            cout << " " << i;
        }
    }

    // Prime Numbers
    cout << "\n\nPrime Numbers";
    cout << "\n************* \n";

    // Prime Numbers Calculation
    for (start; start <= end; start++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j < start; j++)
        {
            if (start % j == 0)
            {
                chk++;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Prime Numbers Output
        if (chk == 0)
            cout << start << " ";
        chk = 0;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

**My guess for the error with this code is the fact that all 5 of my programs have `int main()` but as far as I know you need it in all programs?**

I don't really know what to do as this is my first time making a project with 5 different files as I need to "Compress the entire project folder for each task that contains VC++ file, cpp file, sln file, debug folder etc and upload entire folder compressed"

Comment: If one project comprises multiple files, then indeed, only one of them can have a `main()` function. It's really not clear from your exposition how these files are related to each other. Their relationship is probably more important than the actual code. Please [edit] to clarify. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: ... But somehow it actually sounds like you should put them in separate projects if they are meant to be separate executables. Again, the exposition leaves us guessing more than what is healthy for a well-defined question.

Comment: @tripleee They aren't all related to each other. They are separate code for separate programs. I've just been told that it needs to be compressed into a folder

Comment: The quote at the end sounds like they _could_ mean create five projects and compress and upload _each_ separately. Where does this come from? If you are taking a course, probably ask your professor or a teaching assistant for clarification.

Comment: @tripleee I've tried asking my professor but I do all of my work remotely (perks of this study) but they literally don't reply...

Comment: Pretty extreme to require that you compress the entire thing. Visual Studio generates lots of extra files that you really don't want to be sharing because they can be large. That includes, but is not limited to, IntelliSense database, user settings, and intermediate files such as compiled object code, incremental linker data, and precompiled headers. The only stuff you actually need is the `.vcxproj`, the `.sln`, the `.filters` and your source files. And yes, it sounds like they want each task to be a separate project. You can put them all in one solution, with individual project files.

Comment: I don't think compressed here means put everything in one folder, it means use a compression tool to minimise the size of the upload. Windows has such compression tools built in, right click on a folder, select 'Send to' and then 'Compressed (zipped) folder'.

Comment: Another way is to use `cl.exe` compiles your single cpp file.
`cl.exe /EHsc /ZI T1.cpp`

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate project for each test, and maintain them all in one solution. Here is an example where I make a solution called `Assignment`, and have an initial project called Test1.

[image: Project Wizard Test1]

Now you can right-click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and add another project.

[image: Project Wizard Test2]

In the Solution Explorer, you can then right-click on the project and choose "Add New Item", then create your CPP file. Or you can "Add Existing Item" if you already have your source files in the right place.

So, here I've just got two projects in the solution. You can continue to add more.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Now if I Build All (Ctrl-Shift-B), all the projects are built. Notice in the screenshot above that the `Test1` project is shown in boldface. That means it's the "Startup project", so if you then start debugging (F5), then Test1 will be the program that is executed.

You can change this via the Project menu, or the Project's context menu: right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select "Set as Startup Project". More advanced options regarding Startup Project can be found in the Project menu, under "Configure Startup Projects".

It's not necessary to use Build All. You can just set the Startup Project to whatever one you're working on, and any time you hit F5, it'll only build and run that project. This is because you haven't configured the project to have a dependency on other projects in the solution.

Since your assignment requires you to submit with all the binaries as well, I'd recommend that you do a Clean, then Build All, then test each program before you zip everything up and send.

There's many other ways you might want to set up this solution, but I thought I'd keep it simple and stick to the most straight-forward way using the UI and default directory structure. That gives you the best chance for not getting tangled up.

After this, here's what the root directory structure looks like. Nice and tidy:

[image: Root Folder Structure]

And here's the directory tree. Each project's intermediate files (as a result of compilation) are stored in the `x64` subdirectory in each project folder, whereas the solution's output files (executables and program database) are all in the `x64` root folder.

[image: Directory Tree]

A note on those names: `x64` refers to the project *platform* which in this case is a 64-bit program. If you open the Configuration Manager, you'll probably also see `x86`, which is a 32-bit platform. And you'll also see `Debug` and `Release` which are the two default *configurations* (*i.e.* different groups of build settings for the target platform).